# Excel Macro Copy Selection area and Paste

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I have:

I am trying to get excel to copy only the cells that i have selected and pasted on the next blank line in another spreadsheet.

But in the code below, it fixed the range of cell being copied. How should i change my code so that it can be a dynamic range?

```
Sub CopyPaste()

  Range("A6:E6").Select
  Selection.Copy

  Sheets("Sheet2").Select
  lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
  False, Transpose:=False
  lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the statement

```
Range("A6:E6").Select
```

This statement selects the fixed range.

Try this

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim lMaxRows As Long

    Selection.Copy

    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    lMaxRows = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngTarget = sht.Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1)
    rngTarget.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    lMaxRows = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    sht.Activate
    sht.Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
End Sub
```

I have rewritten the code to specify exactly which cells and ranges are used. If not, it will apply selections on the sheet that is open (active) at that moment.

In my experience, using `.Select` is error-prone so I try to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: Wow. Thanks alot! I tot it is a must to have a 'Range' there. Still beginner in excel macro. =)

Comment: No, in this case you do not have to because you have selected a range manually. Everyone starts as a beginner, no problem.

Comment: One more problem, why when i apply the code in a command button to run the coding, it appear "Run-Time Error 1004 :Select method of Range Class failed."? But is has NO problem when i run it as macro.